# Why im a getting this PEP-warning?

Tags: pygame, pep

I get a lot of these pep-warnings in my Pygame:

```
Expected type 'bool', got 'int' instead
```

They're all related to variables like this where I define the font for my text:

```
welcome = welcome_font.render("Welcome to mosquito hunt! ", 1, (0, 0, 0))
```

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Comment: The second argument to [render](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) is `antialias`, presumably that should be a boolean (`True`) rather than an integer (`1`), although I'd guess it'll work fine with any [truth-y value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument of `render` is boolean and controls the atialiasing. It has to be `True` rather than `1`:

```py
welcome = welcome_font.render('text', True, (0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Thanx, that was it

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know why

You are getting the warning "Expected type 'bool', got 'int' instead", because in *some place* you are passing an `int` where Python is expecting a `bool`.

> and how to fix?

In the place where you are passing an `int` and Python is expecting a `bool`, pass a `bool` instead of an `int`.

The *most likely* place is here:

> ```python
> welcome = welcome_font.render("Welcome to mosquito hunt! ", 1, (0, 0, 0))
> #                                                           ↑
> ```

[The documentation for `pygame.font.Font.render(text, antialias, color, background=None) -> Surface`](https://pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) says:

> The antialias argument is a boolean: if true the characters will have smooth edges.

So, the second argument to the call should be a boolean, i.e. it should be either `True` or `False`:

```python
welcome = welcome_font.render("Welcome to mosquito hunt! ", True, (0, 0, 0))
#                                                           ↑↑↑↑
```